# JHipster Registry - Problems deploying to ECS

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka, jhipster-registry

I am trying to deploy JHipster registry to ECS - that's an OOTB 7.1.0 image. I created an ECS task, overriding the environment variables in the container definition:

[image: Overriden environment variables]

I also updated EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE and EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME env. variables to point to the correct service discovery URLs, but I keep on getting UnknownHostException when the registry starts:

[image: UnknownHostException]

So it looks like some vars are picked up, while Eureka URLs are still using the defaults... In turn, I am not getting any instances registered:

[image: Empty Eureka page]

Am I just missing how it all works? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: While there were issues with that config before (e.g. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2541), locally, when I start docker container "-e EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=X", it seems to be picked up just fine....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial will he

[Jhipster Registry on ECS Tutorial](https://blog.ippon.tech/jhipster-registry-with-ecs/)

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, Anthony! I actually gave up on trying to figure it out with ECS. Ended up switching to EKS instead where it all worked like charm!

Comment: I did somethig with this guide https://www.jhipster.tech/aws/ using AWS Elastic Beanstalk just one command i just see some problem with se tomcat version but the deploy was fine.

Comment: EKS it's nice but it's expensive, i'm working on some project to be fast and cheaper to deploy jhipster but with quarkus... follow me on twitter @aapiro...